# Undefined variable on view mailing in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Hi guys i'm trying to mail on my system and there's problem on view which is undifined variable of data. i'm trying to parsing data to view, but it seems to be problem. here is my code of mailing

```
Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new TagihanMail(),['data' => $data]);
```

and here's my view

```
@component('mail::message')
# TAGIHAN PEMBAYARAN

Berikut tagihan anda untuk pembayaran


@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
{{ $data['nomor_tagihan'] }}
@endcomponent

@component('mail::table')
test
@endcomponent

Terimakasih,<br>
Panitia
@endcomponent
```

hope u guys can help me.

Comment: where your view stored, what is folder structure for this ?

Comment: @Rishi i stored on view with the name of folder "emails"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new TagihanMail($data));
```

and in your `TagihanMail` you can use:

```
public function __construct($data)
{
   $this->data = $data;
}

public function build()
{
     return $this->view('your-view-here')->with(['data' => $this->data]);
}
```

Comment: solved ! thankyou bro, but i still don't get it lol. i will try to understand.

Comment: @AbdanSyakuro :  you can try `['data' => $data]` if `$data` not worked here `send(new TagihanMail($data));`

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass view name directly, like this.

```
Mail::to($data['email'])->send('emails.view_name',['data' => $data]);
```

**Upate**

You can pass data like this

```
$request = ['data' => $data];
Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new TagihanMail($request));
```

Comment: i can't because i use laravel 5.4 mailing markdown , and it needs to use mailing component